# Why a while loop preventing a class to load next time when an application refresh to reload it second time?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-web-start

I am working on a `client(java)-server(c++)` application. We start the application with url in browser `http:\\[ip os server]:[port]. index.html` loads in main browser window and pop-up(application) comes up and this(pop-up) window is responsible for showing up server's features.

We have a class `ShowServerStatusServlet` which is responsible to the server-status ie. unknown/complete.

```
@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException, ServletException
    {
       synchronized (this)
        {
          out.println("<LABEL><B>" + serverStatusLabel_ +
                        "&nbsp;:</B></LABEL>&nbsp;<SPAN ID='ServerStatus'>" +
                        serverStatus_+ "</SPAN>");  
         }  
     }
```

We have one problem that sometimes server-status remain unknown even the application loads fully. This was due to multi threading issue that the above code runs before the application loads fully. So i made a change,

```
synchronized (this)
{
    while(!statusUpdated_)
    {
       try{
           Thread.sleep(20000);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    out.println(.............................    
  //some other code
}
```

It worked.

But the problem i am facing now is, if i cut the pop-up and refresh the main browser which reloads the application pop-up does not have anything related to server stauts(Nothing, the area of displaying status is blank).

And the code without while loop does not have this problem means the server-status is coming even we cut the pop up and refresh again the main browser to launch the application(Pop up).

Thanks in Advance

Comment: 1. You are showing *server Java code* and claiming that only the client is in Java. 2. `synchronized` in `doGet` is surely the wrong thing to do. It will make your server in effect single-threaded.

Comment: Are your (presumably `static`) `serverStatus` fields `volatile`? If not, updates made in other threads may not be visible to the thread handling the request. Consider accessing them in all threads only via synchronization on a common lock object (not `this` - other threads won't have a reference to that)